# Problems of laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I have a big problem, I am trying to create a symbolic link on my server for my Laravel 9 project and it won't let me, I run the php artisan storage:link command and what it creates in the public folder of my project is a file text called storage, the text file says that the storage file does not exist, I already did many things but it won't let me create it

afdf

Comment: You should be more specific and explain more, 
What OS you're using?
Have you tried any shell commands?